# R How to repeat a mean value every minute?

Tags: r, dplyr, timestamp, repeat, lubridate

I have a quite simple problem and I would like to know if there is already a function in R that allows me to do this: 
Here is my tab with a mean valeur for each 5 minutes:

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 00:05:00 | 4 |

I'd like to repeat values for each minute like this :

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 00:01:00 | 1 |
| 00:02:00 | 1 |
| 00:03:00 | 1 |
| 00:04:00 | 1 |
| 00:05:00 | 4 |
| 00:06:00 | 4 |
| 00:07:00 | 4 |
| 00:08:00 | 4 |
| 00:09:00 | 4 |

etc

I'm pretty sure there is a function which return this, maybe in lubridate package but I don't succeed to find it.
Thank you for your help if you know the answer!

Cheers

Comment: The `padr` package can help with this. You might alternately define the moments you want, append them to the data, tidyr::fill down the values, and filter for distinct moments.

Comment: Or you could use `tidyr::uncount` with an id column, and then use that in a `mutate` to make new times.

Comment: Ok, I'm a beginner in code, I will look at this, thank you !

Comment: Your input and output shows it is incrementing by seconds if the format is `HH:MM::SS`

Comment: padr package seems interesting but the thing is I have a lot (more than 100) columns with values, not only one. In the function, I think I can fill only one column... 
I'll try with the other option

Comment: Oops you're right I made a mistake in my TS.. It's every minutes yes, not every second

Comment: `{lubridate}` is part of the (wider) `{tidyverse}` and deals with the handling of (date)time objects. You can create "sequences" of time with base `seq()`. To fill the empty rows there are handy helpers in `{tidyr}` another tidyverse package: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html.